# Breeze.js Passthrough Predicate Odata Url

Tags: breeze, predicate, predicatebuilder

I am attempting to create an odata url with multiple breeze.js passthrough predicates using documentation from the folowing link: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-using-json.

However the generated url looks nothing like an odata url eg:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('User').using(this.manager).where("{ { 'userName': { '=': '123456' } } }");
var url = query._toUri(this.manager);
```

url is `"User?$filter=%7B%20%7B%20'userName'%3A%20%7B%20'%3D'%3A%20'123456'%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D&$orderby=UserName"` rather than `"User?$filter=(UserName eq '123456')&$orderby=UserName"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a passthru query because this just passes your where clause thru intact without any processing. This is what happens when you quote the entire where clause.

If you want your query converted to 'odata' syntax then try the following:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customers').using(em)
     .where({ 'userName': { '==': '123456' } });
```

Note that the 'where' argument is NOT in quotes ( it is a standard javascript object), and the operator is '==', not '=';

or even simpler

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customers').using(em)
     .where( { userName: '123456' });
```

### Further info:

There are two forms of urls that can be generated from ***any*** breeze query.  An OData form and a JSON form.  If you want OData, (the default) then you either do nothing because it is the default or you can tell breeze explicitly with:

```
breeze.core.config.initializeAdapterInstance("uriBuilder", "odata");
```

If you want the json form, you would use

```
breeze.core.config.initializeAdapterInstance("uriBuilder", "json");
```

It also possible that you added a line to use the 'json' uriBuilder.  Just omit this line if you want OData urls. You can still construct the query via the json syntax, but the URL will be output using OData syntax.

The Json form ( or uri) is useful for non OData servers.